# Is it possible to handle http modules in core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have an old application build in MVC and now i am migrating it in asp.net core but i am not able to handle http modules in core. Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: Google is your friend... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP.NET Core application, the [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) component will replace both the HTTP handler and modules. It is a component that is executed on every request. We can add the middleware in the Configure method of the Startup class using the IApplicationBuilder interface.

We can use the following four methods of the Application Builder file that are passed to the Request Delegate.

**Run** To terminate the HTTP pipeline.

**Use** To add the middleware to the request pipeline.

**Map** To match the request delegate based on the request path.

**MapWhen** Supports predicate-based middleware branching, allowing separate pipelines.

The official document gives relevant examples：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thank you Mr/Mrs/Miss. Caodeng this was very helpfull.